# I need a regular expression to insert some code at the beginning of each line in Webuilder

Tags: regex

I'm using Webuilder to do all my coding and I run into a tedious task,
I need to insert some repetitive code at the start of each line and I thought maybe, this can be done using a regex...
But, I'm using Webuilder and can't seem to get it to work, I looked at several alike questions but none provided the answer.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the solution of your problem is regex as regex is used in string for find and replace feature not to add some code.

Comment: Maybe, but the Search and Replace dialog has in the past helped me using regular expressions for other tasks.

Comment: Try "search for:"  `^` (that is the "start of line" anchor) and put whatever you want into "replace with"

Comment: try $ or \n (\n will work for all except first line probably)

Comment: I updated the image above to better illustrate my point.

Comment: -Nabeel Khan Thank You!
The \n did the work, I Love You... Thank You a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks to Nabeel Khan advice, I was able to execute the task I was stuck whit.

I  used: \n to insert at the beginning of each row at once and \r to insert something else at the end. I thank you all.

\n  to insert at start of row and  \r  to insert at the end of each row.

hope this helps someone else. :)